# IntelliSense: no operator >> matches these operands

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am trying to figure out why I keep getting the compiler error

**IntelliSense: no operator ">>" matches these operands**

with the code below. Would appreciate any help given. Thanks

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 int main(void)
 {
      int n;//number of resources we will  be dealing with 
      cout <<"What is number of resources to be shared?"<<
      cin >> n;
      return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

```
cout <<"What is number of resources to be shared?"<<
cin >> n;
```

Is the same as:

```
cout <<"What is number of resources to be shared?"<< cin >> n;
```

---

Perhaps `<<` should be followed by something like `std::endl;`, just or changed to a `;`.